# Blockchain API Help - How to check if payment was complete?

Tags: javascript, api, bitcoin

Ok so I read the code from their demo but am having a problem understanding.

I have successfully implemented their API functionality so that it generates an address that users can send to, but I want it to check if the payment was completed and check the amount they sent and update their balance.

How do I do this?

https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive

!(http://puu.sh/3q9Ss.png)

That is their documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are two ways you can go. It looks like you are using the receive api (https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive) but I reccomend to use the main api (https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api) which has much more features. As far as your question goes, it explains on the page how to create a callback url. Once you set a callback url you will receive a notification when a payment is received but its recommended that you wait for atleast 1 (3 is recommended, 6 is the best) before actually sending the product as people can create double spends.

Answer (score -1):

That all about your callback url :)

You make generate address forwarding. And make sure your callback url working.
If ur customer send payment for u via temp address. blockchain will be call your callback url.

When confirmations >= 6. Just active or update ur customer's balance :) Dont forget check btc value too.